# Using $httpBackend in developement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-mock

In my Angular application I want to use `$httpBackend` to fake the data while development(and not while testing). The problem with using it while development is that all the requests initiated to fetch the static resources like template html or css fails with it.

```
angular.js:14516 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: views/login.html (HTTP status: undefined undefined)(…)
```

As shown above after including the `$httpBackend` service to application it starts to complain about the http templates.

```
angular
  .module('myApp', ['ngResource','ui.router','ngMockE2E'])
  .config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider.state('dashboard.contacts',{
        url: '/contacts/:id',
        views:{
          'mainWrapper':{
            templateUrl: 'views/contacts.html',
            controller:'ContactsCtrl as contactsctl'
          }
        },
      });
  })
  .run(function ($state, $rootScope, AuthenticationService, $httpBackend) {
    var contacts = [{'id':1,'name':'ABC','phone':1234},
      {'id':2,'name':'DEF','phone':3456},
      {'id':3,'name':'GHI','phone':5678}];

    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    if(!AuthenticationService.isAuthenticated()) {
      $state.transitionTo('login');
    }

    $httpBackend.whenGET('/contacts').respond(contacts);
  })
  .controller('ContactsCtrl', function(){
    var contactsctl = this;
  });
```

What is best way to generate some fake data in angular application in `BackendLess` way while development ?

Comment: I think there is couple ways of doing that. `$httpBackend` is for testing and I think you shouldn't use it for your production code. What you can do, is to set some proxy server up and direct your API calls to it. It can be even on your local machine. It's almost like a production, but instead of accessing a DB, you return your mockups.

Comment: I don't want to do that production, but I need some fake data while development.

Comment: You can try these out: https://github.com/typicode/json-server , https://github.com/json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker